# decorator for extra thread

Tags: python, multithreading, decorator

I am trying to automate tasks behind a gui. My gui has multiple buttons that are supposed to start certain functions and one button to stop any function that is currently running. When one function is running, all buttons except the "cancel" button are greyed out. I need the extra thread so that my gui is still responding while the lengthy functions are running.

Now I would like to implement one decorator to decorate those functions. This decorator should run the function in a separate thread. When the user presses the cancel button the function in this extra thread should receive some kind of stop signal which the decorated function can use to stop its current task and exit.

I know that it's possible to implement a class of type threading.Thread for each function and insert the current function as "def run(self):", but it does not seem like an elegant solution.

Is there a way? To me it seems like a common problem, but I have not found any solution via Google except to write the functions as classes and run those as separate threads.

Edit 1:

Let me add some examples. Right now my functions look like this:

```
def function1:
    function_code
```

But if I create classes it would look like this:

```
class class1(threading.Thread):
    stopper = None
    def __init__(self):
        init_code
    def run(self):
        function_code

 def function1:
    t = class1()
    t.stopper = some_stop_condition
    t.run()
```

The second code is much longer and needs a class and a function for every button. It just seems so much more complicated and I hope it's unnecessary.

Am I wrong or am I doing something wrong?

Edit 2:

My new Code, after salomonderossi's great example:

```
def run_async(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def async_func(*args, **kwargs):
        queue = Queue.Queue()
        t = threading.Thread(target=func, args=(queue,) + args, kwargs=kwargs)
        t.start()
        return queue, t

    return async_func


# @layout_decorators.runInSeparateThread()
@run_async
def test2(myQueue):
    print "executing test2"
    import time
    for k in range(6):
        print k
        try:
            myQueue.get(False)
        except Queue.Empty:
            print "cancelled"
            return
        time.sleep(1)


def test22():
    print "executing test22"
    global globalQueue
    globalQueue, t = test2()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import time
    print "\n\n"
    test22()
    time.sleep(2)
    globalQueue.put("stop")
```

But it stops the thread at the first chance. Even if I remove the last line (which I thought stops the thread) my output is

```
executing test22
executing test2
0
cancelled
```

Comment: Why is the class `threading.Thread` not a elegant solution?

Comment: @AlexHall: I don't want to kill it, I want the function to handle the stop signal and exit by itself.

Comment: @julivico: Because I would have to write 5 classes instead of 5 functions and a decorator. Those classes would be identical except for the run-function inside. I know that I could inherit from one of them and change the run-function for each of them. Still seems too complicated for this seemingly simple task.

Comment: It isn't more complicated, in fact it is simpler and not only that, it is more easily read and maintained. You are falling into the trap of less code is better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The decorator needs to create a way to comminucate with the thread. In this example every function which should be run as a thread must have the `queue` argument at first place. This `queue` is used to communicate with the threads. In this example anything can be put in the queue to stop the thread, because the function only checks if a value can be put out of the queue.

With `queue.get(False)` the function tries to get a element from the queue (without waiting). If there is no element (the queue is empty) an Exception is raised. Otherwise there is something in the queue and the thread is told to quit.

To tell the thread to quit, something has to be put in the thread queue. This is done with `queue.put("stop")`. In this case the argument doesn't matter.

This means, you have to check regullary if there is something in the queue and react to it (In this case just stop processing).

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from threading import Thread
from functools import wraps
from time import sleep

try:
    import queue as Queue
except ImportError:
    import Queue as Queue


def run_async(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def async_func(*args, **kwargs):
        queue = Queue.Queue()
        t = Thread(target=func, args=(queue,) + args, kwargs=kwargs)
        t.start()
        return queue, t

    return async_func

@run_async
def do_something_else(queue):
    while True:
        sleep(1)
        print("doing something else")
        # check if something in the queue and return if so
        try:
            queue.get(False)
        except Queue.Empty:
            pass
        else:
            print("Told to quit")
            return


@run_async
def print_somedata(queue):
    print('starting print_somedata')
    sleep(2)
    try:
        queue.get(False)
    except Queue.Empty:
        pass
    else:
        print("Told to quit")
        return

    print('print_somedata: 2 sec passed')
    sleep(2)
    try:
        queue.get(False)
    except Queue.Empty:
        pass
    else:
        print("Told to quit")
        return

    print('print_somedata: another 2 sec passed')
    sleep(2)
    try:
        queue.get(False)
    except Queue.Empty:
        pass
    else:
        print("Told to quit")
        return

    print('finished print_somedata')


def test():
    threads = list()

    # at this moment the thread is created and starts immediately
    threads.append(print_somedata())
    print('back in main')

    # at this moment the thread is created and starts immediately
    threads.append(print_somedata())
    print('back in main')

    # at this moment the hread is created and starts immediately
    threads.append(do_something_else())
    print('back in main')

    # at this moment the hread is created and starts immediately
    threads.append(do_something_else())
    print('back in main')

    print("Wait a bit in the main")
    sleep(1)  # uncomment the wait here to stop the threads very fast ;)

    # you don't have to wait explicitly, as the threads are already
    # running. This is just an example to show how to interact with
    # the threads
    for queue, t in threads:
        print("Tell thread to stop: %s", t)
        queue.put('stop')
        #t.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Comment: That's not what I mean. I don't want multiple tasks and wait for all of them. I want 1 task, not wait at all and have an option to send a stop-request to the function running in this task.

Comment: @Stefan you don't have to wait, you could just call `print_somedata()` and keep going. He's just shown how you could also have access to the thread if you wanted which is often important (such was when you *do* need to wait for the tasks to end, or at least check if they've finished, which is often).  The option to stop the thread cannot be added to the decorator, and in fact if it could it wouldn't be a good idea because that's a separate concern. But you said you want the function to stop gracefully, so you will need to code that manually each time because it won't always be the same thing.

Comment: @salomonderossi: It looks as if I should be able to understand the rest by myself, but I don't get it. How can I send a stop command? If I put "if stopFlag: return" in between all the print & sleep statements, how can I edit this from the main function and stop the threads before they print "finished print_somedata"?

Comment: @salomonderossi: So queue.put('stop') somehow empties the queue which in turn makes queue.get(False) return a Queue.Empty-Error. I still don't fully understand why it works this way (specifically why the queue.put('stop') command empties the queue), but I can research this part myself. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I think I got it: If the item that was put into the queue is not of type Queue.Queue then the item is not immediately available (as explained [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) under Queue.get()) and therefore raises the mentioned error.

Comment: nope ... I did not get it. have edited the question above again :-(

Comment: @Stefan I made a mistake in my code and corrected it a while ago. The `try ... except ... else` block is now correct. Sorry for not mention it...

Comment: @salomonderossi: Now it finally works. I would not have been able to do it without help and I think I learned a lot. Thanks a lot you for your help and patience!